# laravel 5.7: RedirectResponse::__construct() problem

Tags: laravel-5.7

> [larvel 5.7] Argument 2 passed to
>   Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\RedirectResponse::__construct() must
>   be of the type int, array given, called in
>   C:\xampp\htdocs\ecole\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Routing\Redirector.php
>   on line 203

Comment: Please add some context to whats happening and what you are trying to do

Comment: the problem has resolved

Answer (score 0):

```
namespace App\Http\Middleware;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use Fideloper\Proxy\TrustProxies as Middleware;

class TrustProxies extends Middleware
{
    /**
     * The trusted proxies for this application.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $proxies;

    /**
     * The headers that should be used to detect proxies.
     *
     * @var string
     */
    protected $headers = Request::HEADER_X_FORWARDED_ALL;
}
```